# How to create a sub array from another array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

How to create a sub-array from another array? Is there a method that takes the indexes from the first array such as:

```
methodName(object array, int start, int end)
```

I don't want to go over making loops and making my program suffer.

I keep getting error:

> cannot find symbol method copyOfRange(int[],int,int)

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class testing 
{
    public static void main(String [] arg) 
    {   
        int[] src = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
        int b1[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(src, 0, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 402):

You can use

### JDK > 1.5

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(Object[] src, int from, int to)
```

[Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

### JDK <= 1.5

```
System.arraycopy(Object[] src, int srcStartIndex, Object[] dest, int dstStartIndex, int lengthOfCopiedIndices);
```

[Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Comment: I was having some issues with not having Object[]s in my Arrays.copyOfRange. Check your imports to ensure you are using java.util.Arrays. Somehow a different Arrays version got imported and I wasted 15 minutes checking JREs and JDKs for the issue.

Comment: @NuclearPeon Thank you!!! Would have taken me a long while before I figured it out myself. Eclipse automatically imported `org.bouncycastle.util.Arrays`.

Comment: This is actually a copy of a part of an array. A sub-array would be pointing to the original array like a sub-list. Changing an array element will not affect the original array whereas in a sub-array it would. Also it has performance implications as not only the pointers are copied, but all elements (for objects shallow copy).

Answer (score 147):

`Arrays.copyOfRange(..)` was added in Java 1.6. So perhaps you don't have the latest version. If it's not possible to upgrade, look at `System.arraycopy(..)`

Comment: @Sami either upgrade to 1.6 or see this doc for reference http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: Which vendor is your JDK from. Sun/Oracle never released a version 4.00.28 and google couldn't find it either.

Comment: copyOfRange nulls trailing elements if they are out of source array range instead of allocating a smaller array :(

Comment: someone should add in the answer that while "start-index" is inclusive, "end-index" is *exclusive*

Comment: @YanKingYin you are correct--this is precisely what I was reading the comments for :)

Answer (score 22):

Yes, it's called [System.arraycopy(Object, int, Object, int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) .

It's still going to perform a loop somewhere though, unless this can get optimized into something like `REP STOSW` by the JIT (in which case the loop is inside the CPU).

```
int[] src = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] dst = new int[3];

System.arraycopy(src, 1, dst, 0, 3); // Copies 2, 3, 4 into dst
```

Answer (score 17):

**JDK >= 1.8**

I agree with all the answers above. There is also a nice way with Java 8 Streams:

```
int[] subArr = IntStream.range(startInclusive, endExclusive)
                        .map(i -> src[i])
                        .toArray();
```

The benefit about this is, it can be useful for many different types of "src" array and helps to improve writing pipeline operations on the stream.

Not particular about this question, but for example, if the source array was `double[]` and we wanted to take `average()` of the sub-array:

```
double avg = IntStream.range(startInclusive, endExclusive)
                    .mapToDouble(index -> src[index])
                    .average()
                    .getAsDouble();
```

Comment: Good idea to use streams. One could also use `Stream.of(source).skip(start).limit(count).toArray(Foo[]::new)`.

Answer (score 8):

Using Apache [ArrayUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) downloadable at [this link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) you can easy use the method

```
subarray(boolean[] array, int startIndexInclusive, int endIndexExclusive)
```

"boolean" is only an example, there are methods for all primitives java types

Answer (score 4):

```
int newArrayLength = 30; 

int[] newArray = new int[newArrayLength];

System.arrayCopy(oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, newArray.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct so I'm guessing that you are using an older JDK.  The javadoc for that method says it has been there since 1.6.  At the command line type:

```
java -version
```

I'm guessing that you are not running 1.6

Answer (score 1):

I you are using java prior to version 1.6 use `System.arraycopy()` instead. Or upgrade your environment.

Answer (score 1):

For Java >= 1.8

```
Arrays.stream(array, incIndex, exclusiveIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

OP said they didn't want a for loop but in case anyone does:

```
int[] subArr = new int[end - start];

for (int i = 0; i < end - start; i++){
    subArr[i] = sourceArr[i + start];
}
```