# Indexing Java Arrays coming from a Matlab Background

Tags: java, arrays, matlab

Hello StackExchange Community,
I am noob with Java and want to index elements of an array MATLAB style. E.g., In MATLAB if I want to read the last 10 elements of an array I can type:

```
someArray = someOtherArray(end-10:end);
```

In Java, I can only think to use a for-loop, which seems rather inconvenient. Are there array methods in Java that do this? Should I write my own class and methods? Why or why not?
Thanks,
Kyle

P.S. I am actually trying to create a Processing sketch, but it seems Java rules of array usage have been inherited.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439595/how-to-create-a-sub-array-from-another-array-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(array, start, end) may help.
```

Comment: That doesn't look like legal Java to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy of your Array

```
someArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(someOtherArray,end-10, end);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ArrayUtils.subarray() method

Documentation: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html

Comment: As of Java 6, you can use `Arrays.copyOfRange(array, start, end)`. No need for a third-party package.