# Keep array elements based on the size inputted

Tags: java

I have a string array

String `ipist[] = { "817", "818", "819", "820", "821" };`

My requirement is if the input is 2

ipist should be

```
ipist[] = { "817", "818" };
```

for input 4

```
ipist[] = { "817", "818", "819", "820" }
```

that is based on the input need to keep the array elements

Comment: [`ipist = Arrays.copyOfRange(ipist, 0, input)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-)

Comment: Thank you. Can u post ur answer.?so that I can accept that

Comment: Use `Arrays.copyOfRange`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439595/how-to-create-a-sub-array-from-another-array-in-java).

Comment: You can use Arrays.copyOfRange or else you can use following code,


            int j = 0;
  while(j < 4)
  {
   System.out.println(ipist[j]);
   j++;
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Arrays.copyOfRange(T[] original, int from, int to)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-) *(Java 6+)*:

```
String[] ipist = { "817", "818", "819", "820", "821" };
int input = 3;

ipist = Arrays.copyOfRange(ipist, 0, input);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ipist));
```

*Output*

```
[817, 818, 819]
```